# No Debug page in Visual Studio project's property pages

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

All of the MS documentation that I can find says to go to Project -> Properties -> Debug in order to see the "Debugger Type" option. I have no such "Debug" property page and I can't find any "Debugger Type" option anywhere else. I have both VS 2013 Pro Update 4 and VS 2012 Pro Update 4 installed.

In VS2013, there is supposed to be the following options for Debugger Type: Managed Only, Native Only, Mixed (Managed and Native), Script Only and Native with Script.

The only debug options close to this, that I can find, are under Project -> Properties -> Web, where there are check boxes for ASP.NET, Native Code, SQL Server and Silverlight and "Enable Edit & Continue". These options don't appear to match what the Debugger Type option is asking for.

Also, I don't understand why  my property pages for a project so different from in the documentation that I find. [JavaScript/Native Interop Debugging in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/28/javascript-native-interop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?PageIndex=1#comments)
 and [Mixed Native and Managed Debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/16/mixed-native-and-managed-debugging-improvements-for-windows-store-apps.aspx)
For most projects I have the property pages:  Application, Build, Web, Package/Publish Web, Package/Publish SQL, Silverlight Applications, Build Events, Resources, Settings, Reference Paths, Signing, Code Analysis.
Why are are my property pages so different from what I see on these two links? And where do I find documentation for the options that I am seeing?

I should add that I tried creating all of the Web project types under C#: Empty, MVC3 & MVC4 (empty and internet templates), WebForms. I get the same for property pages.